# wordpress media library pagination

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am doing a site for a library, and they've ended up having more images than anticipated.

I'm wondering if there is a standard way for wordpress to paginate the amount of images shown in a gallery. These guys tend to have at least in excess of a 100 images and I would really like to display them as 8x8 = 64 before pagination begins.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I found this very handy little plugin called jquery.pajinate.

Easy to use easy to embed and solved the problem instantly

Comment: Appel, can you post the link to the plugin please?